# Sitecore List Manager: add new contact

Tags: sitecore

I'm trying to add new contact to empty list in Sitecore List Manager. I click "Create and add new contact", type appropriate data and click "Save" button. After that I get following messages:

> Please note that this list is currently being built and is locked.

and

> Please note that contacts in the list are currently being indexed, so not all contacts are available to view at this time. 0 out of 1 contacts are currently indexed.

Then I use "Index manager" and rebuild "Sitecore_list_index". After that, I go back to List Manager and unlock list manually.

Finally, I can't see any contacts in the list. Can't figure out what's wrong.

**EDITED**

Sitecore version is 8.1 (it was upgraded from 8.0)

Comment: What version are you on? I see in 8.0 there was a contact locking issue. Look at List Manager at the bottom of this list. https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/616431

Comment: @dnstommy, I have upgraded Sitecore version from 8.0 to 8.1. Looks like unlocking works fine

Comment: Great to hear. Can you approve the answer below?

Comment: @dnstommy, sorry, my fault. I meant my current Sitecore version is 8.1 (it was upgraded from 8.0 couple weeks ago), unlocking works fine, but I'm still not able to add contacts. So, my problem is still opened.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue in 8.0, there was a contact locking issue. Look at List Manager at the bottom of this list. An upgrade should fix the issue.

kb.sitecore.net/articles/616431